# change Original table values when group by Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query that does 3 group bys. What I want to do is to group null and 0 values together. Or change all the null values to 0 in a specific column. And get the count of that group having 0s. Also I want to assign a "NA" value to the group containg 0s.

What I want to get is the "HowMuchSpent" Group to appear as 0 for null values, and the "Count" to include them in one group. Any help would be great. Thanks in Advance

My Query as follows:

```
var MAList = 
    (
        from vwBudgetPop in dbContext.vw_MonitoringAsst_Budget_PO
        join clientfile in dbContext.ClientFiles on vwBudgetPop.ClientFile_ID equals clientfile.ID  
        group vwBudgetPop by new { clientfile.CountryID_DestinationCountry } into grouped                                                       
        join clientfile2 in dbContext.ClientFiles on grouped.FirstOrDefault().ClientFile_ID equals clientfile2.ID
        join country in dbContext.Countries on clientfile2.CountryID_DestinationCountry equals country.ID

        select new
        {
            Country = clientfile2.Country2.Country1 ?? "NA",
            ChoiceList = from maX in grouped
            group maX by maX.Choice_ID into g2                                              
            join choice in dbContext.Choices on g2.FirstOrDefault().Choice_ID equals choice.ID 

            select new
            {
                Choice = choice.Choice123,
                HmSpentList = 
                    from gd in g2                                                                 
                    group gd by gd.HowMuchSpent_ID  into hmGroup                                                                
                    join hmSpent in dbContext.HowMuchSpents on hmGroup.FirstOrDefault().HowMuchSpent_ID equals hmSpent.ID into hmSpentfull
                    from hm in hmSpentfull.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new
                    {
                        HowMuchSpent = hmSpentfull.FirstOrDefault().HowMuchSpent1,
                        Count = hmGroup.Count()
                    }
            }
        }
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: What is the error? Or what are you getting as output?

Comment: I am getting the output grouped like - Choice 1 : <null - 5, 0 - 6, HowMuchSpent1 - 8, HowMuchSpent2 - 7>. What I want get is something like - Choice 1 : < NA - 11, HowMuchSpent1 - 8, HowMuchSpent2 - 7>